# How to check if hyperlink target's name contains a specific string?

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I have cells in a workbook that link to cells that are named (individually). The cell names all start with "Filter", with some string after that (e.g. FilterSubcategory1").

If the user clicks one of the links, it takes them to the linked cell and then filters another sheet based on where the target was (using `.Address` at the moment, all works fine). As they all have the same starting string in their name, is it possible to filter if the target name starts with "Filter" instead? This would make my code far shorter rather than listing all relevant named ranges.

It would look something like this (for illustrative purposes, not my full or optimised code):

```vb
If Target.Range.Name = "Filter" & "*" Then
'rest of code, do the filtering
End If
```

or:

```vb
If InStr(Target.Range.Name, "Filter") > 0 Then
'rest of code, do the filtering
End If
```

Comment: You could loop through all the `Names`, check if they begin with `Filter`, then check if their `RefersToRange` `Intersect`s with `Target`. I don't think `Range.Name` is very reliable.

Comment: Can you better explain what does "hyperlink target's name" mean? Is it a real range name? Is it used to set the hyperlink Address/SubAddress?

Comment: The target is a named range, and the hyperlink subaddress is to the target's name, not it's cell reference (A1, etc.). I think that's what you mean.

Comment: Then, you may build a function checking it. It should look like, but I will better post an answer, to also see how to be checked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after trying other users' solutions (very helpful in the lead up to the solution), I managed to solve it in a different way. Some hyperlinks linked to themselves (in fact, all the ones that filter do), some linked to merged cells too, so this was the method I used for any cells that linked to themselves:

```
FltrStr = "='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & ActiveCell.Address     'builds up the cell address from scratch, allowing for a merged cell being selected
Set FltrRng = Range(FltrStr)     'converts the string into the actual range needed, important for the next line
FltrName = FltrRng.Name.Name     'gets the name of the range, reporting the given name if it exists, lookup .name.name if you are unsure why two .names are needed
```

I can then use this to check if the target range has a name which starts with whatever I want, here 'Filter':

```
If InStr(FltrName, "Filter") > 0 Then
    'rest of code, do the filtering
End If
```

Probably not the prettiest/most efficient way to do it, but it works. May be worth defining the types of the variables (FltrStr, FltrRng, FltrName) explicitly at the start of the sub to avoid any type mismatch errors, but I haven't defined them at the moment and they are working fine. (Bad practice, I know!)

Comment: This is a naive/bad question with a naive pseudo answer... If it points to itself, this only means that the cell in discussion is the named range you search for. The hyperlink does not matter at all. It could matter only if you would try using the `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` event... I do not bother to vote it down.

Comment: I apologise again that my question and answer were not up to standard. I will try to include more relevant information in future questions. The filtering happens within a `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` event, which is why I thought the hyperlinks were important to start with, but as I played with code I managed to solve it without use of the `Target.Range` or `SubAddress` properties. This was not how I planned to solve it, hence the change in direction with my answer. I'm sorry for the problems I have caused.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next function:

```
Function IsFilter(cel As Range) As Boolean
    If cel.Hyperlinks.Count = 0 Then Exit Function
    If InStr(cel.Hyperlinks.SubAddress, "Filter") > 0 Then IsFilter = True
End Function
```

The above function can be use in the next way:

```
Sub testIsFilter()
    Dim testCell As Range
    
    Set testCell = ActiveCell 'it may be any cell (resulted from a iteration or not)
    If IsFilter(testCell) Then
        'rest of code, do the filtering
    End If
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried playing with it, but some of the hyperlinks link to themselves, and some are merged cells so I think that played havoc with the code and I couldn't adapt it to work. In the end, I solved the problem a different way, I have posted my solution as an answer.

Comment: Apologies, I was writing the solution as you replied here. I didn't mention the merged cells/self-reference thing as I didn't think that was relevant at the time as some linked to other cells/non-merged cells, but I now see that it was likely useful information. I apologise again, and feel free to downvote my solution if you feel it is not what I asked. I have only posted it in case someone comes across this in future and has a similar set up to me.